# Create new dataframe with condtion per groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create new dataframe based on condition per groupby.
Suppose, I have dataframe with Name, Flag and Month.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Flag':[0, 1, 0, 1], 'Month':[1,2,1,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

need = df.loc[df['Flag'] == 0].groupby(['Name'], as_index = False)['Month'].min()
```

My condition is to find minimum month where flag equal to 0 per name.

I have used `.loc` to define my condition, it works fine but I found that it quite poor performance when applying with 10 million of rows.

Any more efficient way to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: If no better solution, you can pass `sort=False` to `groupby` to make if faster.

Comment: I think `dask` should help here, because large data.

Comment: u mind sharing how long it took u to run it

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same scenario yesterday, where I took a 90 second process down to about 3 seconds. Because speed is your concern (like mine was), and not using solely Pandas itself, I would recommend using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) and [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). The catch is you're going to have to brush up on your data structures and types to get a good grasp on what Numba is really doing with JIT. Once you do though, it rocks.

I would recommend finding a way to get every value in your DataFrame to an integer. For your name column, try unique ID's. Flag and month already look good.

```py
name_ids = []
for i, name in enumerate(np.unique(df["Name"])):
  name_ids.append({i: name})
```

Then, create a function and loop the old-fashioned way:

```py
@njit
def really_fast_numba_loop(data):
  for row in data:
    # do stuff
  return data

new_df = really_fast_numba_loop(data)
```

The first time your function is called in your file, it will be about the same speed as it would elsewhere, but all the other times it will be lightning fast. So, the trick is finding the balance between what to put in the function and what to put in its outside loop.

In either case, when you're done processing your values, convert your `name_ids` back to strings and wrap your data in `pd.DataFrame`.

Et voila. You just beat Pandas iterrows/itertuples.

Comment back if you have questions!

Comment: I think `aggregation of min` is in pandas is cython optimalize, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions), so numba here should be faster? Not sure. Also your code not aggregate min.

Comment: First off, you rock. You have no idea how much I've used your work over my career. Thanks a ton. Second, I agree with you there are lots of ways we could slice this problem by looking under the hood. With the scenario I had, I had the same question as OP, and with my approach above I ended up beating out Pandas. It took a lot of profiling though. And it definitely wasn't pythonic. But, it got me the result I needed, and hopefully it will get OP the same.

Comment: First, I want only say, not sure if faster way is this operation in numba.  So is possible create solution with aggregate `min` and test it in some large dataframe, e.g. 10M rows, 10k groups and compare?

Comment: I think it's ultimately up to OP. You recommended Dask (good idea), another person recommend passing `sort=False`, which I assume will keep current code working and increase speed, although I don't know how much and if it will be acceptable to OP. My solution worked for me, I was happy with it. So, we have 3 solutions for OP to try. Let's see what OP says and move from there? I say this because the question is subjective. "How do I make this faster" could be done lots of ways, and may not be best for their project.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But your solution is only pseodocode, it not aggregate `min`. so canot be compared with OP code.

Comment: I'll leave it for now and return to edit when I have more time, and based on OP's responses. Who knows, maybe we'll have to use all three solutions.